# How to preserve original attributes (modified date, permissions, etc) when copying files (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, file-transfer, attributes

I have an oldish computer with four ~500 GB 3.5" hard drives installed and there are perhaps a dozen partitions total. What I want to do is make a collated backup of all of these files on a single 2 TB portable 2.5" drive, and instead of multiple partitions, there will be multiple folders stored inside a folder called 'Old Computer' instead.

I would like to copy the files so that the attributes are the same on both the origin and destination, previously I [Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V] copied the files from one drive and the date of the folders on the new location matched the actual time of copying, which I don't want, I find it useful to see when a folder was originally created, so I want to keep all these the same.

Any ideas?

Comment: For convenience, a partition could be Zipped, if there is room, keeping the folder structure as well as file attributes (other than *archived*). Moving a single large Zip is faster than many small files, though time is taken Zipping them.

Comment: Here is a nice utility for that...https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain there is an option inside Robocopy to do just this.

Run help on robocopy (robocopy /?) and look for /COPY and /COPYALL arguments.